# Radioactive Babyface

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Radioactive Babyface]

Clues: [Contextual Images]
[hexagon made of 6 shapes]
[polygon filled with letters]
[alien at a bar]

Instructions: Name That Castle

_ _ â _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ è _ _ _

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first attempt was to do this, which gave me nothing:

> [image: 1]

So instead, I realized it made more sense to attempt this:

> [image: 2]

By doing this, I am left with:

> `H R G E R I G`, as well as the last photo and title. As mentioned in the comment, These letters can be rearranged to form one name, H R Giger (as per the hint in the comments).

Doing this gets me to what I believe to be the solution:

> Giger bought a castle, the Saint-Germain Castle in Gruyères. In French, château can be translated to mean castle. Therefore, the answer is:
>  `_ _ a _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ e _ _ _`
>  `c h a t e a u d e g r u y e r e s`

Additionally:

> H R Giger was the artist who designed the xenomorph in the Alien movie series, which solves the last photo (thank you again to the comment)

OP Edit:

> The title is a 2-part hint. 
>  
> Hint 1 refers to the wall of tortured babies that cover one wall of the HR Giger bar in Château de Gruyères [image: Baby Wall]
>  
>  Hint 2 is that a Geiger Counter is used to detect radiation.

> If you're ever in Gruyères Switzerland, be sure to visit this amazing place[image: Giger Bar]
>  
> [image]
> [image: Giger Bar 2]

Comment: You got the first part right! The letters all combine to spell one name.

Comment: ROT13: Gur yrggref yrsg bire fcryy U E Tvtre, gur negvfg jub qrfvtarq gur krabzbecu va gur Nyvra zbivr frevrf. Tvtre chepunfrq n pnfgyr, Fnvag-Treznva Pnfgyr va Tehlrerf, juvpu ubhfrf n zhfrhz bs Tvtre'f jbex. Ohg V pna'g frr ubj gung svgf jvgu gur ninvynoyr oynax fcnprf. Gur orfg V pna qb vf "Pungrnh va Tehlrerf".

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the answer is

> Château de Montrésor

When I saw the â and è, I thought of castles in France. I looked up "list of castles in France" and found this.
I also looked up the meaning of Château and found that it meant "a large French country house or castle, often giving its name to **wine** made in its neighborhood."
I think that is why shows an alien at a **bar**.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is right, but either way it's not particularly useful when you haven't addressed most of the clues. Do you have any explanation for the hexagon or the shape filled with letters?

Comment: Given the answer doesn't even fit the blanks, I'll go out on a limb and say it's not right.